# Update is not working on GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sqldatasource

Hey guys,
I have a GridView which is binded to SqlDataSource, everything works fine, just update does not works, i am calling stored procedure, and all parameters and its dataTypes are proper, actually none of the events work on that update button, i tried to change the CommandName to "Change" and created OnCommand Event, and wrote Response Message in the code. but nothing happens on the update button, cancel button works fine, and also delete works, there is just a problem with update, even if the procedure has some issue atleast event should raised, i even checked in Sql Profiler, but the update procedure never hits Sql Server 2008...

But when i remove SqlDataSource then everything works fine also the update command with same stored procedure.

Please help me out for this, i have stuck here badly

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Title" EnableModelValidation="True"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
    ShowFooter="True" Width="950" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Title") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtEditTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quote">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Quote") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditQuote" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quote") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField >
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quote Link">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("QuoteLink") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditQuoteLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuoteLink") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Published">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Published")) %>' Enabled = "false" />  
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Published") %>' Enabled="true" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PublishedDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PublishedDate")).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditPublishedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PublishedDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Edit" ImageUrl="/images/edit.gif" CommandName="Edit" />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Delete" ImageUrl="/images/delete.gif" CommandName="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Cancel" ImageUrl="/images/delete.gif" CommandName="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Quotes] WHERE [Title] = @Title"
    SelectCommand= "SELECT [Title], [Quote], [QuoteLink], [Published], [PublishedDate] FROM [Quotes]" 
    UpdateCommand="sp_UpdateQuotes" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Quotes] ([Title], [Quote], [QuoteLink], [Published], [PublishedDate]) VALUES (@Title, @Quote, @QuoteLink, @Published, @PublishedDate)">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quote" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="QuoteLink" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Published" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishedDate" Type="DateTime" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quote" Type="String" DefaultValue = "QUotes are simple" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="QuoteLink" Type="String" DefaultValue = "QUotes are Linked" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Published" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue = "False" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishedDate" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue = "05/15/2011" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateQuotes]

    @Title varchar(max),

    @Quote varchar(max),

    @QuoteLink varchar(max),

    @Published bit,

    @PublishedDate DateTime

AS

BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.Quotes SET

    Quote = @Quote,

    QuoteLink = @QuoteLink,

    Published = @Published,

    PublishedDate = @PublishedDate`

```
WHERE Title = @Title  

If @Published = 1  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE dbo.Quotes SET Published = 0 WHERE Title <> @Title AND Published = 1  
END
```

END

Hope this would give you clear idea about what is messing me for update

Comment: Please post your code, so that we can have idea where is the issue.

Comment: 1+ for @Muhammad for that reasonable comment :)

Comment: not sure here but I had a nearly same problem once. somewhere u are using Eval(".."). try to bind those columns as you did with others and try after that. anything changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed the `@Title parameter`, which is your primary Key in your stored procedure and is used in the `where Clause`.

If you want to see that there is no Title Parameter in Update Parameters:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Quote" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="QuoteLink" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Published" Type="Boolean" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="PublishedDate" Type="DateTime" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

If you add the Title Parameter, it will work:

```
    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
```

Comment: @Mohammad: I specified title parameter also but still same issue, actually the button event does not just raises, if it throw any error i can try something to resolve, but when i click on update it just do nothing

Comment: now something wiered happened, i have edit and delete button inside Itemtemplate and update and cancel in EditItemtemplate, now when i applied CommandName="Update" to Edit Button, the updating works properly, is there any issue with the editItemtemplate, as the same application is running on my local machine, with EditItemtemplate having CommandName="Update"... ANy suggestion what could be done

Comment: Can you replace this <%# Eval("Title") %> with <%# Bind("Title") %> ? Let me know your findings.

Comment: Your Edit button command Name should be "Update", It does not matter it in Command Field or in Template field. Gridview Update event only fire when there Command Name = "Update" Button clicked in the gridview.

Comment: i updated as you said, check in the original post above, but still the same, when i put the CommandName = "update" under the button which is inside EditItemTemplate, update never takes place but when i put the CommandName="Update" inside button under ItemTemplate it works

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with a GridView that was not updating. Inspection of the e.Newvalues Dictionary in the GridView's RowUpdating event showed that the old values for the record were being sent to the database UPDATE query.  DataKeyNames was not my problem; I had it set correctly. The WHERE clause of my SELECT query referenced a control parameter against a TextBox on my form.  I had inadvertently set EnableViewState for this textbox to "False". Because of this, the GridView was rebinding itself before the UPDATE occurred. Setting EnableViewState on the TextBox to "True" fixed the problem.

```
    Protected Sub MyGridView_RowUpdating _
    (sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) _
    Handles MyGridView.RowUpdating

    ' Inspect the parameters being sent to the database for an ASP NET GridView UPDATE.

    Dim I As Integer

    I = 0

    For Each MVO As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In e.OldValues
        If MVO.Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse MVO.Value Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVO.Key + " Value:  ")
        Else
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVO.Key + " Value:  " + MVO.Value.ToString)
        End If

        I += 1
    Next MVO

    I = 0
    For Each MVN As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In e.NewValues
        If MVN.Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse MVN.Value Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVN.Key + " Value:  ")
        Else
            Debug.Print(I.ToString + ": " + MVN.Key + " Value:  " + MVN.Value.ToString)
        End If
        I += 1
    Next MVN


End Sub
```